# I'm not able to understand this code in tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, logic, init

```
init_tuple = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]

result = sum(n for _, n in init_tuple)

print(result)
```

The output for this code is 6. Could someone explain how it worked?

Comment: You unpack each tuple into the variables `_` and `n` then just sum the second. It might help to look at what this produces: `[n for _, n in init_tuple]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get better understanding first look at this.

```
init_tuple = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
sum = 0
for x,y in init_tuple:
     sum = sum + y
print(sum)
```

Now, you can see that what above code does is that it calculate sum of second elements of tuple, its equivalent to your code as both does same job.

```
for x,y in init_tuple:
```

x hold first value of tuple and y hold second of tuple, in first iteration:

*x = 0, y = 1*,

then in second iteration:

*x = 1, y = 2* and so on.
In your case you don't need first element of tuple so you just use **_** instead of using variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code extracts each tuple and sums all values in the second position (i.e. [1]).

If you rewrite it in loops, it may be easier to understand:

```
init_tuple = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
result = 0
for (val1, val2) in init_tuple:
    result = result + val2

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(n for _, n in init_tuple)` is a generator expression.  You can iterate on such an expression to get all the values it generates.  In that case it reads as: *generate the second component of each tuple of `init_tuple`*.

(Note on `_`:  The `_` here stands for the first component of the tuple.  It is common in python to use this name when you don't care about the variable it refers to (i.e., if you don't plan to use it) as it is the case here.  Another way to write your generator would then be `(tup[1] for tup in init_tuple)`)

You can iterate over a generator expression using for loop.  For example:

```py
>>> for x in (n for _, n in init_tuple):
>>>   print(x)
1
2
3
```

And of course, since you can iterate on a generator expression, you can sum it as you have done in your code.